# Trying to figure out how to install Apache for linux

Tags: permissions, software-installation, apache-httpd

I'm following these set of instructions from this link here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/install.html (and following instructions from a guide book as well- which isn't going too well)

I got the APR/APR util properly done; based off the book it uses `gunzip -c httpd___.tar.gz | tar -xf -`

I extracted these files but wasn't sure how to unpack it into "/httpd_source_tree_root/srclib/apr and /httpd_source_tree_root/srclib/apr-util "

Am I supposed to do : `gunzip -c httpd___.tar.gz | tar -xf - C/home/Downloads/httpd_source__xxxxx` ?

Tried playing around with the terminal but couldn't get it to work, so I extracted it using the default method from above, and copied/pasted it into /srclib/apr and scrclib/apr-util.

This brings me to the configure step. I've been looking around on stack exchange but couldn't find a solution right for me. ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663180/http-install-error-in-libpcre)

I downloaded the PCRE, extracted it. And now here comes the part where I am completely lost and would appreciate any help/directions/or answers. 
What I tried so far

1) I copied/pasted the extracted PCRE into the /srclib as pcre. From the terminal, I cd'd my way into the httpd directory and tried this

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/pcre

make
make install
```

which gave me an error

```
/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/local/pcre': Permission denied
make[2]: *** [install-libLTLIBRARIES] Error 1
```

I tried other multiple ways but kept getting the same PCRE error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this really any more than a simple permissions issue? `/usr/local/` is a system directory, so if `make install` needs to write there, you need to run it as root - the appropriate way to do that (`su`, `sudo` etc.) will depend on what distribution/flavor of Linux you are running.

Comment: Do you really want to compile all yourself and not use distribution provided packages?

Comment: I see. Should of looked more into what sudo was instead of blindly use it. Thanks.
@sami is it better in the long run to learn to compile all this myself/manually than to use a package for everything? Have been wasting a lot of time with trial and error through the terminal rather than learning html, etc